# swift - I'm dumb and my subview wont obey and correctly size itself

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview

I feel like this is a softball for you veterans, but I'm having a lot of trouble resizing the subview of my UIImageView... here is what I got:

```
var myImageView:UIImageView!

var tmpView:UIImageView!
```

myImageView is my "main" UIImageView, and I'm treating tmpView as a subview... now I've tried both with and without auto layout on, but I've set the constraints of myImageView s.t. myImageView takes up the whole screen. I've confirmed this to be true by setting myImageView.image = UIImage...etc.

Here is my code for initializing the image and adding it to the subview:

```
self.tmpView.image = UIImage(named: "myImage.png")
self.tmpView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 300)
self.imageView2.addSubview(self.tmpView)
```

Now here is where I am running into problems - no matter what I set tmpView's height and width to, the size never changes. Interestingly though, changing x,y does have an effect on the position of the subview.

Here are my questions: 1) Why do both x and y obey nicely, but width and height do not?

2) How do I fix this, and is it best to do so programmatically or through the storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should no longer modify the frames directly when using autolayout. Add a width and height constraint to `tmpView`, and create outlets for them if you're using IB (The outlets should have the type `NSLayoutContraint`).

You can also create the constraints in code but there's no point of doing it that way unless you have to.

In both cases, to resize `tmpView`, change the `constant` property of each of the constraints to the values you want.

```
widthConstraint.constant = yourNewWidth;
heightConstraint.constant = yourNewHeight;
```

Comment: @säculnój: This is the correct method; if it's not working then you may need to change the priority on the constraints. I recommend you use the view debugger to check the constraints at runtime.